# How to Fill color of Google Maps data layers on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geojson, google-datalayer

I am trying to draw a Google Map with a state (Texas) filled with a grey background, and a city (San Antonio) with a lighter background (white). my approach is this:

```
  var stateLayer = new google.maps.Data();
  var countyLayer = new google.maps.Data();

  stateLayer.loadGeoJson('state.json');
  countyLayer.loadGeoJson('county.json');

  stateLayer.setStyle({
    fillColor: 'gray',
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1
  });

  countyLayer.setStyle({
    fillColor: '#fff',
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1
  });

  stateLayer.setMap(map);
  countyLayer.setMap(map);
```

but the result that i get is gray all over the state (including the county).

please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kob490/rcLsy73b/4)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including any required GeoJSON.

Comment: sure. please see the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kob490/rcLsy73b/4/. I'm trying to make the inner county polygon in the same color like the rest of the map excluding Texas.

Comment: Seems like what you want is a hole in the texas polygon.  To make that you need to include the San Antonio polygon in it with a reverse winding direction (at least that works with normal polygons).

Comment: can you post a sample for this? I've seen examples of holes in polygons, but non of those worked based on my json (some of which are actually (MultiPolygons)

Comment: I don't have a sample.  You might be able to create it and test it faster than me (I tried a quick test that worked with geojsonlint.com but didn't work with the Google Maps Javascript API v3 DataLayer)

Comment: Actually [here is a quick sample](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rcLsy73b/7/), simple rectangular polygon with a rectangular hole.

Comment: [Here is a San Antonio.hole in a world sized polygon](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rcLsy73b/11/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The world sample is helpful. but I'm still wondering about the Texas scenario. I think this has not worked for me in the same way because the Texas JSON consists of a Geometry type of MultiPolygon. whereas the County is a single polygon. Thus, i could never create a "hole" that way.

Comment: I know, I would think there would be a way to modify the "Texas" MultiPolygon to work, but it will take some experimentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to make a "hole" in the Texas MultiPolygon where San Antonio is:

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcLsy73b/21/)

**code snippet:** (note due to character limitations in the post the code snippet includes a simplified polygon for Texas, the fiddle contains the full MultiPolygon)

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: 29.424122,
      lng: -98.493629
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    zoom: 5
  });

  // Load GeoJSON.
  var stateLayer = new google.maps.Data();
  var countyLayer = new google.maps.Data();

  stateLayer.addGeoJson(stateGeoJson);
  countyLayer.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/3inb5');

  stateLayer.setStyle({
    fillColor: 'gray',
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1
  });

  countyLayer.setStyle({
    fillColor: 'red',  // make red so I can see that it is working
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1
  });

  stateLayer.setMap(map);
  countyLayer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var stateGeoJson = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"GEO_ID":"0400000US48","STATE":"48","NAME":"Texas"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[
// simplified texas
[[[-106.6552734375,32.0639555946604],[-103.0078125,32.0639555946604],[-103.0078125,36.491973470593685],[-99.9755859375,36.491973470593685],[-99.9755859375,34.59704151614417],[-99.0087890625,34.23451236236984],[-97.822265625,33.90689555128866],[-96.240234375,33.687781758439364],[-95.09765625,33.870415550941836],[-94.0869140625,33.43144133557529],[-94.0869140625,31.989441837922904],[-93.3837890625,31.05293398570514],[-93.9990234375,29.611670115197377],[-97.1630859375,27.916766641249065],[-97.470703125,26.745610382199025],[-97.03125,26.03704188651584],[-97.5146484375,25.878994400196202],[-99.140625,26.509904531413927],[-99.5361328125,27.68352808378776],[-100.3271484375,28.34306490482549],[-100.72265625,29.19053283229458],[-101.42578125,29.726222319395507],[-102.6123046875,29.76437737516313],[-103.095703125,28.998531814051795],[-104.6337890625,29.649868677972304],[-104.8974609375,30.524413269923986],[-106.6552734375,32.0639555946604]],
// san antonio
[[-98.68846,29.21083],
[-98.682015,29.20863],
[-98.63851,29.193774],
[-98.625318,29.189273],
[-98.590587,29.177251],
[-98.585943,29.175655],
[-98.58573,29.175582],
[-98.557348,29.165861],
[-98.547608,29.162526],
[-98.526902,29.155435],
[-98.52462,29.154688],
[-98.524215,29.154515],
[-98.497539,29.14541],
[-98.484266,29.140821],
[-98.484041,29.140744],
[-98.465819,29.134476],
[-98.441548,29.126127],
[-98.441456,29.126092],
[-98.431298,29.122507],
[-98.407336,29.114435],
[-98.397585,29.125244],
[-98.372654,29.1555],
[-98.330197,29.206269],
[-98.327196,29.209868],
[-98.304559,29.237003],
[-98.303019,29.23885],
[-98.300464,29.24191],
[-98.295924,29.247353],
[-98.29568,29.250546],
[-98.29246,29.251235],
[-98.28702,29.257626],
[-98.283214,29.26233],
[-98.255615,29.296176],
[-98.249288,29.303938],
[-98.237988,29.317737],
[-98.20469,29.358113],
[-98.204587,29.358236],
[-98.188143,29.378514],
[-98.138033,29.439391],
[-98.137187,29.440428],
[-98.134171,29.441751],
[-98.129128,29.444268],
[-98.128681,29.445363],
[-98.12512,29.446405],
[-98.120922,29.446476],
[-98.121075,29.449048],
[-98.124107,29.453224],
[-98.126771,29.454736],
[-98.126864,29.457223],
[-98.125594,29.45824],
[-98.123575,29.457675],
[-98.120243,29.457468],
[-98.117774,29.46023],
[-98.117033,29.461925],
[-98.116902,29.463884],
[-98.118722,29.469263],
[-98.120577,29.470841],
[-98.121138,29.473542],
[-98.122276,29.473019],
[-98.124087,29.474003],
[-98.12488,29.475642],
[-98.123057,29.47638],
[-98.122322,29.477646],
[-98.12514,29.480196],
[-98.125881,29.481648],
[-98.128986,29.482453],
[-98.131106,29.481381],
[-98.131861,29.480127],
[-98.134125,29.478923],
[-98.136269,29.479265],
[-98.137092,29.481191],
[-98.136802,29.482495],
[-98.135481,29.483089],
[-98.13565,29.484216],
[-98.137172,29.484234],
[-98.139449,29.482485],
[-98.14058,29.484152],
[-98.139491,29.485549],
[-98.141786,29.486485],
[-98.143622,29.485743],
[-98.142793,29.484027],
[-98.144466,29.484231],
[-98.143982,29.482492],
[-98.142467,29.481611],
[-98.142959,29.479741],
[-98.144229,29.47813],
[-98.150015,29.475667],
[-98.150989,29.476278],
[-98.150156,29.479752],
[-98.150786,29.48058],
[-98.152409,29.478616],
[-98.155754,29.477809],
[-98.159124,29.478651],
[-98.1613,29.477716],
[-98.164638,29.478091],
[-98.166581,29.479439],
[-98.166832,29.482036],
[-98.168767,29.487092],
[-98.166943,29.489622],
[-98.168288,29.491169],
[-98.168344,29.496153],
[-98.169381,29.497528],
[-98.171507,29.496747],
[-98.172583,29.494503],
[-98.173764,29.496627],
[-98.176336,29.496688],
[-98.178625,29.497662],
[-98.181543,29.497392],
[-98.183807,29.495747],
[-98.184914,29.493393],
[-98.184323,29.492716],
[-98.180456,29.492782],
[-98.179092,29.490911],
[-98.179651,29.489569],
[-98.177608,29.487176],
[-98.176923,29.485399],
[-98.178017,29.484442],
[-98.18311,29.484899],
[-98.187592,29.488212],
[-98.188694,29.491363],
[-98.189964,29.492843],
[-98.18975,29.49665],
[-98.188285,29.499412],
[-98.186324,29.5012],
[-98.1899,29.505719],
[-98.190148,29.509328],
[-98.195356,29.51111],
[-98.195891,29.510103],
[-98.198573,29.509365],
[-98.200237,29.511445],
[-98.19969,29.513596],
[-98.19701,29.514757],
[-98.196923,29.515731],
[-98.198571,29.517326],
[-98.201885,29.516869],
[-98.202533,29.517705],
[-98.201332,29.519048],
[-98.204779,29.52215],
[-98.208403,29.522529],
[-98.209975,29.523365],
[-98.214272,29.522963],
[-98.216354,29.524349],
[-98.218467,29.523369],
[-98.219147,29.52393],
[-98.219368,29.528533],
[-98.221078,29.531246],
[-98.222182,29.534811],
[-98.222146,29.537986],
[-98.224399,29.540312],
[-98.229439,29.54195],
[-98.229455,29.543401],
[-98.224413,29.543463],
[-98.22168,29.544381],
[-98.221332,29.544362],
[-98.220965,29.545248],
[-98.22094,29.546194],
[-98.221589,29.547932],
[-98.222653,29.549032],
[-98.224912,29.549681],
[-98.225432,29.549718],
[-98.226352,29.549642],
[-98.226666,29.54941],
[-98.227105,29.547141],
[-98.229565,29.54669],
[-98.230589,29.548108],
[-98.230695,29.550837],
[-98.233899,29.554893],
[-98.239204,29.556575],
[-98.242992,29.557058],
[-98.246402,29.556],
[-98.248931,29.554596],
[-98.248885,29.551521],
[-98.250755,29.550017],
[-98.253796,29.550311],
[-98.255361,29.552332],
[-98.254636,29.554009],
[-98.255605,29.554917],
[-98.25853,29.554935],
[-98.259621,29.552449],
[-98.260075,29.549621],
[-98.25937,29.547487],
[-98.257806,29.545714],
[-98.253881,29.544211],
[-98.253021,29.54321],
[-98.253882,29.540982],
[-98.255377,29.540491],
[-98.259746,29.541265],
[-98.260658,29.542349],
[-98.264818,29.543949],
[-98.267432,29.544178],
[-98.270389,29.54573],
[-98.27084,29.548822],
[-98.272924,29.550878],
[-98.272973,29.550913],
[-98.273036,29.550913],
[-98.27333,29.551006],
[-98.279069,29.551141],
[-98.284329,29.553365],
[-98.287782,29.559373],
[-98.294766,29.561531],
[-98.298524,29.561141],
[-98.298328,29.56322],
[-98.29985,29.566868],
[-98.2999,29.566918],
[-98.301539,29.568342],
[-98.301882,29.568759],
[-98.301938,29.568828],
[-98.302308,29.569476],
[-98.302903,29.574654],
[-98.305066,29.576303],
[-98.306073,29.579114],
[-98.303927,29.582426],
[-98.304431,29.58522],
[-98.310636,29.589182],
[-98.312058,29.590854],
[-98.310928,29.594473],
[-98.31095,29.59456],
[-98.310837,29.598332],
[-98.312033,29.601543],
[-98.313292,29.602236],
[-98.31348,29.602263],
[-98.313494,29.602279],
[-98.314806,29.602844],
[-98.320456,29.601939],
[-98.326234,29.604079],
[-98.328651,29.608233],
[-98.328736,29.610537],
[-98.335328,29.611301],
[-98.339187,29.6131],
[-98.34234,29.617193],
[-98.345121,29.618092],
[-98.345673,29.619742],
[-98.342715,29.62195],
[-98.342271,29.62556],
[-98.340861,29.627541],
[-98.340604,29.630237],
[-98.343052,29.634768],
[-98.343351,29.635138],
[-98.343401,29.63532],
[-98.343672,29.635611],
[-98.343874,29.635952],
[-98.344178,29.63638],
[-98.346072,29.639313],
[-98.347618,29.645018],
[-98.3434,29.650993],
[-98.342733,29.653442],
[-98.345108,29.655058],
[-98.356629,29.658648],
[-98.359781,29.662987],
[-98.360802,29.665226],
[-98.363764,29.666732],
[-98.370994,29.664303],
[-98.377117,29.662728],
[-98.378906,29.662949],
[-98.380541,29.668434],
[-98.380854,29.671906],
[-98.381646,29.674085],
[-98.382419,29.674429],
[-98.382452,29.674443],
[-98.382566,29.67446],
[-98.384341,29.676534],
[-98.384113,29.678591],
[-98.381781,29.680455],
[-98.377325,29.682918],
[-98.376315,29.687055],
[-98.376711,29.689041],
[-98.380827,29.696283],
[-98.380523,29.699539],
[-98.380965,29.701485],
[-98.380161,29.703929],
[-98.375874,29.706215],
[-98.374595,29.706273],
[-98.371274,29.705],
[-98.368087,29.705647],
[-98.362327,29.70597],
[-98.35722,29.703912],
[-98.354557,29.703864],
[-98.35128,29.704867],
[-98.347273,29.706777],
[-98.344689,29.707239],
[-98.342868,29.708384],
[-98.34135,29.70965],
[-98.340367,29.711795],
[-98.340361,29.715819],
[-98.338724,29.71705],
[-98.338006,29.719146],
[-98.338618,29.721786],
[-98.341505,29.723337],
[-98.346283,29.726703],
[-98.349208,29.727511],
[-98.350208,29.728748],
[-98.352406,29.731884],
[-98.352205,29.73415],
[-98.355817,29.734072],
[-98.35672,29.732885],
[-98.356825,29.732614],
[-98.35692,29.732452],
[-98.359382,29.729037],
[-98.364366,29.724332],
[-98.369828,29.720693],
[-98.37521,29.719975],
[-98.375644,29.722654],
[-98.374999,29.724619],
[-98.3735,29.726022],
[-98.373248,29.729186],
[-98.373729,29.730594],
[-98.376967,29.732618],
[-98.384353,29.735141],
[-98.388262,29.733943],
[-98.390972,29.73648],
[-98.393632,29.736481],
[-98.399172,29.738111],
[-98.398262,29.742842],
[-98.402087,29.746859],
[-98.403272,29.748824],
[-98.407786,29.748599],
[-98.410834,29.747426],
[-98.416064,29.746549],
[-98.418984,29.744937],
[-98.420673,29.743529],
[-98.421765,29.740377],
[-98.421803,29.738842],
[-98.42048,29.733814],
[-98.417851,29.733318],
[-98.416887,29.731695],
[-98.418627,29.729489],
[-98.421048,29.728879],
[-98.425908,29.727015],
[-98.429955,29.723588],
[-98.426842,29.71769],
[-98.430926,29.715754],
[-98.438955,29.715765],
[-98.441217,29.716627],
[-98.443852,29.71965],
[-98.444704,29.722466],
[-98.444606,29.726149],
[-98.442918,29.730471],
[-98.442681,29.732286],
[-98.443671,29.734646],
[-98.446778,29.735983],
[-98.451203,29.734403],
[-98.452479,29.733207],
[-98.452595,29.732802],
[-98.457494,29.731564],
[-98.459366,29.731773],
[-98.462127,29.733505],
[-98.464959,29.738115],
[-98.465974,29.738538],
[-98.468471,29.737861],
[-98.471647,29.736298],
[-98.473972,29.734366],
[-98.476991,29.733436],
[-98.479778,29.73508],
[-98.485332,29.735832],
[-98.487935,29.735897],
[-98.48975,29.73534],
[-98.492354,29.735934],
[-98.493023,29.737034],
[-98.496957,29.73849],
[-98.50115,29.738241],
[-98.503974,29.738644],
[-98.507188,29.739795],
[-98.509728,29.741259],
[-98.514491,29.742856],
[-98.516226,29.743083],
[-98.520241,29.744905],
[-98.523374,29.745242],
[-98.526086,29.743416],
[-98.525381,29.740786],
[-98.526781,29.740445],
[-98.528192,29.742228],
[-98.528286,29.743659],
[-98.533959,29.74679],
[-98.533625,29.750505],
[-98.534015,29.752353],
[-98.536575,29.752843],
[-98.538996,29.751903],
[-98.543718,29.752052],
[-98.547306,29.753615],
[-98.547867,29.754391],
[-98.546882,29.757301],
[-98.548067,29.759997],
[-98.550489,29.760713],
[-98.553017,29.76019],
[-98.554997,29.758633],
[-98.555117,29.755255],
[-98.558359,29.751975],
[-98.559304,29.751482],
[-98.562614,29.751476],
[-98.562967,29.752153],
[-98.565545,29.752659],
[-98.566838,29.751922],
[-98.569321,29.748274],
[-98.572107,29.749715],
[-98.574567,29.750419],
[-98.575216,29.750001],
[-98.576407,29.747107],
[-98.579294,29.745478],
[-98.578928,29.743597],
[-98.581475,29.742782],
[-98.582849,29.741137],
[-98.586682,29.742451],
[-98.587496,29.746418],
[-98.588493,29.747595],
[-98.591412,29.747215],
[-98.593113,29.745679],
[-98.596972,29.747362],
[-98.600406,29.74998],
[-98.603404,29.749522],
[-98.604739,29.747255],
[-98.60129,29.744874],
[-98.599997,29.743031],
[-98.600469,29.741265],
[-98.603381,29.739933],
[-98.607473,29.740455],
[-98.611599,29.740063],
[-98.614198,29.737591],
[-98.617092,29.739098],
[-98.616924,29.742916],
[-98.619232,29.744142],
[-98.623339,29.743933],
[-98.628756,29.744146],
[-98.63288,29.741936],
[-98.640969,29.740228],
[-98.644736,29.741184],
[-98.646119,29.744587],
[-98.64613,29.744736],
[-98.646098,29.745071],
[-98.646124,29.745181],
[-98.645551,29.747977],
[-98.64776,29.749809],
[-98.649778,29.7535],
[-98.652501,29.75354],
[-98.653347,29.75135],
[-98.653051,29.748831],
[-98.655989,29.747775],
[-98.658515,29.749207],
[-98.658826,29.749239],
[-98.6593,29.749211],
[-98.661108,29.7493],
[-98.663738,29.746275],
[-98.663391,29.745131],
[-98.660567,29.743722],
[-98.659704,29.742137],
[-98.663241,29.741027],
[-98.668479,29.743476],
[-98.670875,29.743272],
[-98.673832,29.742117],
[-98.674501,29.738805],
[-98.675762,29.737414],
[-98.68141,29.738305],
[-98.682935,29.739351],
[-98.687549,29.73872],
[-98.692725,29.735208],
[-98.699994,29.737441],
[-98.701135,29.735719],
[-98.699888,29.732706],
[-98.701624,29.732343],
[-98.701892,29.732388],
[-98.702695,29.732655],
[-98.703109,29.732883],
[-98.703602,29.733023],
[-98.707789,29.732372],
[-98.710692,29.730851],
[-98.712852,29.728209],
[-98.715592,29.72582],
[-98.717234,29.725275],
[-98.719691,29.726762],
[-98.72302,29.729565],
[-98.726063,29.727748],
[-98.732525,29.729534],
[-98.73383,29.729539],
[-98.733709,29.7279],
[-98.730532,29.725667],
[-98.728797,29.722587],
[-98.733117,29.721566],
[-98.735403,29.719633],
[-98.73777,29.716747],
[-98.743771,29.716359],
[-98.744659,29.718427],
[-98.748051,29.720555],
[-98.750359,29.721016],
[-98.751543,29.720257],
[-98.752918,29.721094],
[-98.757052,29.722026],
[-98.75946,29.722148],
[-98.762252,29.722011],
[-98.766665,29.719554],
[-98.767755,29.720748],
[-98.770843,29.721365],
[-98.771518,29.720458],
[-98.775124,29.719689],
[-98.778782,29.720167],
[-98.802771,29.694835],
[-98.806552,29.690709],
[-98.806415,29.675817],
[-98.805934,29.633678],
[-98.805935,29.633273],
[-98.805941,29.631567],
[-98.805848,29.580936],
[-98.805799,29.572047],
[-98.805743,29.561199],
[-98.805653,29.540013],
[-98.805578,29.522711],
[-98.805341,29.483027],
[-98.805173,29.463057],
[-98.805092,29.447384],
[-98.805002,29.429509],
[-98.804944,29.403889],
[-98.804752,29.365679],
[-98.804751,29.365411],
[-98.804622,29.331826],
[-98.804592,29.323344],
[-98.804878,29.313552],
[-98.804898,29.313209],
[-98.804926,29.312923],
[-98.804868,29.303847],
[-98.804766,29.278959],
[-98.804758,29.250381],
[-98.804756,29.249003],
[-98.804756,29.248586],
[-98.799475,29.248702],
[-98.779769,29.241959],
[-98.775941,29.240645],
[-98.734966,29.22671],
[-98.711643,29.218746],
[-98.711339,29.218643],
[-98.711315,29.218611],
[-98.711234,29.218607],
[-98.68846,29.21083]]]
]}}]};
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```